# Getting an array item

Tags: javascript

so I want to pick a random string from my array and `console.log` it. My code is returning undefined.

```js
var array = [
    "Hello",
    "Hi"
];

var message = array[Math.random() * array.length];

console.log(message)
```

In the `var message` I am trying to get a random message from `array`. Any help would be great!

Comment: You were close, you just have to floor the index since it doesn't work with non-integer values.

Comment: console.log(Math.random() * array.length)

Comment: Try `Math.trunc(Math.random() * array.length)`